# How could I get the Google Site's div width with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get the Google Site's div width with Google Apps Script? But I don't know how to get the width value. I have created a textbox and setWidth("100%"), but I don't know how to get the textbox width. Thanks for help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. That is because your Apps Script resides within the Google Site and it cannot access any of the DOM outside the Apps Script's UI. You can open an issue in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)